# ”SET @CommandText“ in stored procedure with advanced database SQL (seek for explanation.)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am a freshly graduated student who has a very first job in a web company. My boss was asking me to refer to the previous code, and I got stuck while exploring stored procedures. Below is the a snippet of code, can anyone give me some idea on it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQNVT.png)

First, I am wondering the **MEMBER** (from the code). When I open member table in server, there is no attributes like [Bonus Amount], [Bonus Given Amount],[Adjustment Amount]...etc. Can I know where is these element come from / refer to?

Secondly, I need some terms or ideas so that I can have a clearer direction to do online research / self-study. So far what is search from online is helpless for me to understanding the code. I will be very appreciated if receive helps from here.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if you've pasted that "snipped of code" here. Although SO is not a right place to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That command is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh sql server management studio. Sorry for that unclear codes as i can't reveal company confidential. Thank you for help anyway! appreciated!

Comment: @SeM Sorry for that unclear codes as i can't reveal company confidential. Thank you for help anyway! appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is dynamic SQL. That means tables or some where conditions on columns could not be written in plain SQL and need to be executed after full string is created. In Your case `@CubeName` is table name or even more joined tables. That's why You don't see this fields in `MEMBER` table. This stored procedure has variable provided with table/view name.

Comment: thank you so much for comment, i am actually looking for a terms on here to further my study. Sorry for that unclear codes as i can't reveal company confidential. Thank you for help anyway! appreciated!